# Navigations can only target entity types with keys

Tags: .net-core, entity

I am working on a project with a 'database first' approach `rest API` backend. I am using `ASP .Net Core 3.1` and `Entity Framework 3.1.1`.

I ran a script to `scaffold` the `database` into the `models` and `db context class`. However, some of the `model` building `functions` have `tables/models` without keys `x.hasnokey()`. I thought this would be fine but I get an error trying to hit the endpoint that states

```
 ERROR :  InvalidOperationException: 
    The navigation '' cannot be added because it targets the keyless entity type  'AAA'
    Navigations can only target entity types with keys
```

This happens in a few different locations and this originally ran okay in the past. This is running on `SQL Server 2012 (version 11)`. I am not sure how I can solve this issue, I have limited `entity/sql` experience and I just don't know where to begin. Here is the offending lines (inside `DB Context`):

```
modelBuilder.Entity<AAA>(entity =>
        {
            entity.HasNoKey();

            entity.ToTable("BBB_AAA");

            entity.HasOne(d => d.BBB)
                .WithMany(p => p.AAA)
                .HasForeignKey(d => d.CCC)
                .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.ClientSetNull)
...
}
```

The `script` I used to `scaffold` the `models` and `db context` was (generic version):

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\SQLExpress;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

I believe this might be that the `database` that was originally created about 10-15 years ago, cannot be made into an `ORM` so easily as I would have hoped. It could also a `versioning` issue, the `scaffolding script` I ran is incorrect, or if I just am out of my depth but I would appreciate being pointed in the right direction. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This `error` usually comes because of `Primary Key`  issue.
In my Case I was running this query and result was same problem you mentioned

```
 var exists = await _dbDontext.Students.FindAsync(Id);
```

My `Student table` has relations with other `tables` and one of other `tables` was missing `Primary Key`.

So two Possible Solutions .

**Solution 1**  :
Make `Primary Key` column in your `table` that is mentioned in your `error`.

**Solution 2** :
If things are complicated , just delete the `table`  and Re Create It. It would work fine

Answer (score 0):

I think you have two options,

1- Go and add key to the table.

2- check the following link

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/keyless-entity-types

Thanks